# My IOS application crashes when installed from testflight

Tags: ios, ios7, testflight

I have created an ios application which runs well on simulator, and if I install it to a device through xcode using cable it works perfect as well; however if i upload it to testflightapp and install through testflightapp link it crashes.

Comment: Are you using the TestFlight SDK? You should be able to see the error in TestFlight if you are.

Comment: No I am not using TFA's SDK, should i use it. am i missing something during archive process?

Comment: Sync that ipa via itunes and check whether it is crashing or not. If it is crashing then the problem is with your application/ipa

Comment: Can you guide me, how can i do that

Comment: You don't have to use the SDK. However in this instance it would give you easy access to the error which is causing your app to crash.

Answer (score 0):

Hello if you are creating ipa for testflight then it has some different method for creating .ipa for testflight. You have to create payload folder and then by compressing that folder give name of your application like xyz.ipa and then upload it to testflight.

you can also refer this link : http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/402741-how-to-create-an-ipa-xcode-3-

Comment: This is link is for xcode 3. Maybe provide a link for the current version.